# Error when deleting HashMap Element in xmemory0

Tags: c++, pointers, hashmap, destructor

Whenever I try to delete one the elements for my HashMap, I get an error in the C++ code (not my code...the C++ people's code - specifically, xmemory0).  I am sure the error is on my end, but I have no clue where, since the debugger is telling me its elsewhere.  My HashMap has been thoroughly tested, and it seems to function fine except for when I try to delete a HashElement.  I am pretty sure that nothing is pointing to a HashElement before I delete it (which I think would be the first guess).  Can anyone tell why I am getting an error when I try to delete the HashElement?  Here is my stack trace:

```
    msvcr120d.dll!operator delete(void *)   Unknown
>   MyProgram.exe!std::allocator<char>::deallocate(char * _Ptr, unsigned int __formal) Line 573 C++
    MyProgram.exe!std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<char> >::deallocate(char * _Ptr, unsigned int _Count) Line 859    C++
    MyProgram.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Tidy(bool _Built, unsigned int _Newsize) Line 2284 C++
    MyProgram.exe!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >() Line 992 C++
    MyProgram.exe!HashElement::~HashElement() Line 12   C++
```

Here is the code:

**HashElement.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class HashElement
{
private:
    int key_;
    std::string value_;
public:
    HashElement(int, std::string);
    ~HashElement();
    HashElement *next_element_;
    int GetKey();
    std::string GetValue();
};
```

**HashElement.cpp**

```
#include "HashElement.h"

HashElement::HashElement(int key, std::string value)
{
    key_ = key;
    value_ = value;
    next_element_ = nullptr;
}

HashElement::~HashElement()
{
}  //This is the last line before it goes off into not my code

int HashElement::GetKey(){
    return key_;
}

std::string HashElement::GetValue(){
    return value_;
}
```

I will happily post the HashMap itself as well, but I don't think the error is related to the actual HashMap code, so I will leave it out for now to make this post more readable.

EDIT:

Just discovered that the bug does actually lay in my HashMap. Not sure where though.  I am thinking this, because simply creating and deleting a HashElement did not reproduce the error.  But here is the code:

**HashMap.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

#include "HashElement.h"

class HashMap
{
private:
    HashElement **map_;
    int size_;
    int count_;
public:
    HashMap(int);
    ~HashMap();
    int GetHash(int);
    void Put(int, std::string);
    std::string GetElement(int);
    bool Contains(int);
    void Remove(int);
    int GetCount();
};
```

**HashMap.cpp**

```
#include "HashMap.h"

HashMap::HashMap(int size)
{
    size_ = size;
    map_ = new HashElement*[size_]();
}

HashMap::~HashMap()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++){
        int hash = GetHash(i);
        if (!map_[hash]){
            continue;
        }
        HashElement *currentElement = map_[hash];
        HashElement *nextElement = map_[hash];
        while (nextElement->next_element_){
            nextElement = nextElement->next_element_;
            delete currentElement;
            currentElement = nextElement;
        }
        delete currentElement;
    }
}

int HashMap::GetHash(int key){
    return key % size_;
}

void HashMap::Put(int key, std::string value){
    int hash = GetHash(key);
    if (!map_[hash]){
        map_[hash] = new HashElement(key, value);
    }
    else{
        HashElement *lastElement = map_[hash];
        while (lastElement->next_element_){
            lastElement = lastElement->next_element_;
        }
        lastElement->next_element_ = new HashElement(key, value);
    }
    count_++;
}

std::string HashMap::GetElement(int key){
    int hash = GetHash(key);
    if (map_[hash]){
        HashElement *currentElement = map_[hash];
        while (currentElement->GetKey() != key && currentElement->next_element_){
            currentElement = currentElement->next_element_;
        }
        return currentElement->GetValue();
    }
    return nullptr;
}

bool HashMap::Contains(int key){
    int hash = GetHash(key);
    if (map_[hash]){
        HashElement *currentElement = map_[hash];
        while (currentElement->GetKey() != key && currentElement->next_element_){
            currentElement = currentElement->next_element_;
        }
        if (currentElement->GetKey() == key){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void HashMap::Remove(int key){
    if (!Contains(key)){
        return;
    }
    int hash = GetHash(key);
    HashElement *currentElement = map_[hash];
    if (!currentElement->GetKey() == key){
        HashElement *previousElement = currentElement;
        currentElement = currentElement->next_element_;
        while (currentElement->GetKey() != key){
            previousElement = currentElement;
            currentElement = currentElement->next_element_;
        }
        if (currentElement->next_element_){
            previousElement->next_element_ = currentElement->next_element_;
        }
    }
    delete currentElement;
    count_--;
}

int HashMap::GetCount(){
    return count_;
}
```

Comment: Is this a real project or homework? Because you should be using vectors and smart pointers instead of new/delete and I bet the problems will simply disappear.

Comment: It is a portfolio thing. I am intentionally not using smart pointers. If it were a real thing, I'd be C#-ing it :-)

Comment: I don't know what "portfolio thing" means.

Comment: The intent is to showcase a knowledge of pointers and memory allocation. That's why no smart pointers. Real world application is not a concern

Comment: I can't remember: Does this properly initialize the array of pointers to `nullptr`? `map_ = new HashElement*[size_]();`

Comment: @leewangzhong as far as i know, yes. but i dont know very far.

Comment: Correction to comment: You should learn about initialization lists, const member functions and pass strings by const reference.

Comment: @NeilKirk thanks for advice. I'll make that my next venture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received outside help and then help from @leewangzhong in comments.  The issue was in the `Remove()` method of `HashMap.cpp`.  I did indeed have a dangling pointer.  Here is the corrected method:

```
void HashMap::Remove(int key){
    if (!Contains(key)){
        return;
    }
    int hash = GetHash(key);
    HashElement *currentElement = map_[hash];
    if (currentElement->GetKey() == key){
        delete currentElement;
        map_[hash] = nullptr;
    }
    else{
        HashElement *previousElement = currentElement;
        currentElement = currentElement->next_element_;
        while (currentElement->GetKey() != key){
            previousElement = currentElement;
            currentElement = currentElement->next_element_;
        }
        previousElement->next_element_ = currentElement->next_element_;
        delete currentElement;
    }
    count_--;
}
```

Comment: You'll still have a dangling pointer. Remove the check for `if (currentElement->next_element_)`, so that if it's null, `previousElement->next_element_` will be properly set to null. (Also, you do two searches through the table: one for containment, another for removal. The search for containment isn't necessary if you prepare for the possibility of it not containing the element.)

Comment: Isn't that check necessary if the key is found in the final element of the chain?

Comment: Consider what happens to `previousElement->next_element_` if the key is found in the end of the chain.

Comment: That will never run, hence the check

Comment: Yes, but what will be its value (for your current code) when the function returns?

Comment: Try adding an item, removing it, then checking whether it's contained in the hash. I predict a crash or a wrong "true".

Comment: so if `previousElement->next_element_ = currentElement->next_element_;` runs when `currentElement` has no `next_element_`, will that crash or work correctly? (Like edited above)

Comment: What does it mean that `curr` has no `next`? It means that `currentElement -> next_Element_` is null. What does it mean that you're removing the last element of the chain? It means that `prev` now has no `next`. For your current code, `prev` still thinks `curr` is its `next`. Rule of thumb: if you delete something, you should think about whether you need to null something.